# Stubbing a response in an action which calls a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, lambda, microsoft-fakes

I have a service that is called via an action as follows:

```
TheResponseObjectOfTheServiceThatIsCalled response = null;

ServiceCaller.ExecuteCall(serviceName, () => client.Call(p => response = 
      p.MethodWhichCreatesTheResponse(ref header, request)),
                                              callInfo);
// Use the response.
```

Here `p` is the generated interface client which uses a method `MethodWhichCreatesTheResponse` to return a `response` which is used outside of the expression.

Now I want to shim this service to return a custom response via Microsoft Fakes. I can shim the `ServiceCaller` class: the `ExecuteCall` method can return a lambda expression as follows:

```
(serviceName, action, callInfo) => ...
```

This lambda expression has to return `void`.

Is it possible to use this action to set the `response` object?

Comment: Alternatively have the test self host a test version of the service and return the data from that?